# webscraping a table with R rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

As an example to teach myself rvest, I attempted to scrape a website to grab data that's already written in a table format. The only problem is that I can't get an output of the underlying table data.

The only thing I really need is the player column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


base <- "https://www.milb.com/stats/"
base2 <- "?page="
base3 <- "&playerPool=ALL"

html <- read_html(paste0(base,"pacific-coast/","2017",base2,"2",base3))

html2 <- html %>% html_element("#stats-app-root")
html3 <- html2 %>% html_text("#stats-body-table player")
```

https://www.milb.com/stats/pacific-coast/2017?page=2&playerPool=ALL (easy way to see actual example url)

"HTML 2" appears to work, but I'm a little stuck about what to do from there. A couple of different attempts just hit a wall.

once this works, I'll replace text with numbers and do a few for loops (which seems pretty simple).

Answer (score 1):

If you "inspect" the page in chrome, you see it's making a call to download a json file. Just do that yourself...

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- fromJSON("https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2017&sportId=11&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=R&offset=25&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc&playerPool=ALL&leagueIds=112")
df <- data$stats

head(df)

 year playerId       playerName   type rank   playerFullName
1 2017   643256      Adam Cimber player   26      Adam Cimber
2 2017   458547   Vladimir Frias player   27   Vladimir Frias
3 2017   643265   Garrett Cooper player   28   Garrett Cooper
4 2017   542979     Keon Broxton player   29     Keon Broxton
5 2017   600301    Taylor Motter player   30    Taylor Motter
6 2017   624414 Christian Arroyo player   31 Christian Arroyo
...
```